# Install MySQL Workbench in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-installation, 19.04, mysql-workbench

I tried to install MySQL Workbench by:

```
 apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

But I get the following errors and I am unable to install it manually:

```
Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
Depends: libzip4 (>= 0.10) but it is not installable
```

How can I install it?

Comment: You can also use DBeaver communty edition alternatively

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing the `libzip` package, directly from the deb package. I found at [libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb.html).

Download and install `libzip4`, then install `mysql-workbench` from the apt or deb package, whichever you prefer.

Comment: But how can you install mysql-workbench on **19.04** when it is not available on apt??

Comment: Installing via deb gives a lot of dependency errors. On solving each one by one get stuck at libssl1.0.0

Comment: @JayChakra you have to set repositories by installing .deb package from [https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) or you have to install `mysql-workbench` .deb package manually.

Comment: This is what I was quoting above.

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench-community : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installa
`

Comment: Anyways solution by @Luis Alvarado works for me.

Answer (score 17):

so this were the steps I took in order to install it correctly:

1. Download the 2 Libraries that are needed and install them:

   - https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libssl1.0.0/download
   - https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libzip4/download
2. Go to the [MySQL Workbench Download Page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) and Download (At least for now) the latest version for Ubuntu 18.04 and install it. It should install correctly without any issues.

[image]

3. Assuming you already installed the MySQL Client/Server packages, you should be able to see it like this now:

[image]

Note that as of the writing of this answer (April 25, 2019), the package `mysql-workbench` or `mysql-workbench-community` do not exist in the 19.04 repositories (Even with universe repositoy enabled). You can see here that there are not packages created yet: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco/+source/mysql-workbench

Comment: (UNRELATED) How does it feel to have 64 GB ram?

Comment: @Emmet Solitaire lags less.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.  I got stuck on the piece where the first two links didn't actually start downloading.  In case someone else is stuck on this - you actually have to pick one of the mirror links, which will start the download --> click on the downloaded file ---> install.  Derp.

Comment: For me, I didn't need to install libssl, I just installed the libzip4 library and then workbench.

Comment: @JackM thats awesome, it might mean that they are updating everything so it can be installed correctly in the future. Thank you Jack.

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 3):

Even if you check the download site (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), you don't see the released version for 19.04. Looks like we'll have to wait for the version to be released. That is totally a bummer.

Also I can confirm that the 18.10 installer doesn't work on the 19.04

Comment: Okay i was getting frustrated but now i just have to wait

Comment: By now they've added a 19.04 download on the official website.

Answer (score 2):

my libzip4, libzip5 and libzip-dev are installed and have not resolved.

i solved this problem like this:

1-backup or remove these files:
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0

2-locate them in your system:
sudo locate libcrypto.so.1.0.0
sudo locate libssl.so.1.0.0

3-recreate symbolic links for located them: 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed that they took away the 18.10 installer from the download site. Not sure why. May be they're working on getting the 19.04 version out.

Answer (score 0):

After installing these packages:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libssl1.0.0/download

https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libzip4/download

I installed python and it worked

`sudo apt install python`
followed by 
`sudo apt --fix-broken install`
and 
`sudo apt update`

I was able to install workbench designed for ubuntu 18.04 0n ubuntu 19.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it by using: gdebi mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb

It looks up dependencies and installs them, see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gdebi.1.html for more info

Comment: Gdebi isn't going to magically install the missing dependencies mentioned in the question. And what you installed is a different version, that works (also suggested in a commentary) but NOT because of Gdebi.