# How can I install MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench is not supported with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Any solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install MySQL Workbench in Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135823/install-mysql-workbench-in-ubuntu-19-04)

Comment: fallow this tutorial ok for me
https://dev.to/gsudarshan/how-to-install-mysql-and-workbench-on-ubuntu-20-04-localhost-5828

Answer (score 24, accepted):

MySQL has updated their repository for Focal Fossa and removed the repository for Eoan Ermine. To install MySQL Workbench on 20.04, either download the Workbench for 20.04 from [MySQL archives](http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/pool/mysql-tools/m/mysql-workbench-community/) or follow the alternate method mentioned below replacing `eoan` with `focal`.

---

**Historical answer:**

You can download the deb package for Eoan Ermine from [MySQL archives](http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/pool/mysql-tools/m/mysql-workbench-community/mysql-workbench-community_8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb) and install that using:

```
sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb
```

The dependencies of MySQL Workbench for 19.10 are satisfiable on 20.04. APT will ensure installation of the dependencies as well.

Alternatively, you can use MySQL's repository for 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) to get latest updates as soon as pushed in Eoan's repository or until MySQL starts supporting Focal Fossa. To add that:

- Create a new file for MySQL repository:

  ```
  echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ eoan mysql-tools" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
  ```

  and run

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```
- You'll get an error, like

  ```
  Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu eoan InRelease                        
    The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <some key value>
  ```
- Add this key using

  ```
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key value>
  ```
- Update and install MySQL

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community
  ```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The solution #1 worked for me. You saved my day!

Comment: first one worked for me

Comment: If you replace the Historical answer with `focal`, which will be perfect

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me:

```
sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community
```

Comment: **Note:** Workbench snap package isn't maintained by MySQL developers.

Comment: @Kulfy hmm, I wish snap would tell me this, not that it's going to keep me from using it, but it's would be nice to have this information

Comment: @Kulfy according to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html), `mysql-workbench-community` is official package. That said, I believe you would need to [manually add](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-install-components) MySQL APT repository first.

Comment: @AlexanderKucheryuk Yes, but this answer is not about MySQL Workbench deb package or APT repository. This is about [snap package of same name](https://snapcraft.io/mysql-workbench-community).

Comment: @Kulfy D'oh!… was working late and overlooked `snap` in the command. You are completely right! I guess it's a shame that there are 2 different packages by identical name.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that comes here like I did by starting with a google search instead of going directly to the MySQL download page, there is a download explicitly for Ubuntu 20.04 on their downloads page:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has apt repository for ubuntu.

Download MySQL workbench repository config file from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ .

1) Install the downloaded repository config file.

```
sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
```

2) Update apt package list.

```
sudo apt update
```

3) Install MySQL workbench. You will get latest from the repository.

```
sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community
```

Refer these links:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

https://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-mysql-workbench-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Tyler Collier, you can just visit the download page and install it. To make life easier, copy and paste the following commands in the terminal (for Ubuntu 20.10 only, although you can also change the link below next to `wget` command with the one you want for your ubuntu version. [Installation links can be found here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)):

```
$ sudo apt-get install wget
$ mkdir /tmp/mysql_workbench_install && cd /tmp/mysql_workbench_install
$ wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community_8.0.23-1ubuntu20.10_amd64.deb #latest release (13-02-21)
$ sudo dpkg -i *
```

In case something went wrong, or couldn't finish installation due to lack of some dependencies, then:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the proposed solutions installing the .deb file at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ leads to depencies problems on Ubuntu 20.04.

To solve the problem, simply install the missing packages:

```
sudo apt install libpcrecpp0v5

sudo apt install libpython2.7

sudo apt install libzip5
```

Then it worked for me and I could connect to my remote MySQL database with the MySQL Workbench.

Addendum: I found the real reason of the problem: I had NO problem to use the updated workbench for Ubuntu 20.04 on a computer which was itself updated to Ubuntu 20.04 (in my case from Ubuntu 19.10).
But on a NEW computer, which never saw Ubuntu in the past (i bought it 2 days ago and overwrote Windows with Ubuntu 20.04), these packages' dependencies were not satisfied and i had to install them. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Run this then reinstall the mysqlworkbench community

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 0):

To download MySQL-Workbench on Ubuntu 20.04, follow these steps:

1. Go to [MySQL Workbench Archive](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/)
2. In the `Product Version`, choose an older version, like I selcted `8.0.29`. MySQL-Workbench versions later than `8.0.29` are not available for Ubuntu 20.04. So, we need to select the old one.
3. Select `Operating System` as `Ubuntu Linux`

Then you will see the packages of MySQL-Workbench will appear for Ubuntu 20.04.
[image: Screenshot for MySQL Workbench Version Selection for Ubuntu 20.04]