# I want to download mysql workbench on ubuntu. And I keep getting an error

Tags: 20.04

So I searched on the net on how to download mysql workbench and I came to a site which had the instructions(site: https://linuxhint.com/installing_mysql_workbench_ubuntu/). There was one command 'sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.20-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb' and I get the error 'Unsupported file ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.20-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb given on commandline'. What should I do to solve the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.20-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb` ?

Comment: Try this. It worked for me on ubuntu 20.04
https://askubuntu.com/a/1230755/1198372

Comment: The './' on that website seems wrong to me :)

Comment: @MattiaRighetti i tried what you told to do and it shows the messages 'errors occured while processing mysql-workbench-community

Comment: @JainVipray Thanks! I followed the link and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to consider here.

First, in this case `apt` *doesn't* download the package as it would do in most cases. It installs a package you've downloaded before. Please compare

```
sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.20-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

to, for example

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

The latter command tries to locate the package `mysql-server` in the repositories it knows about, then tries to download the package and install it.

In your command, you're providing a relative path, note the `./` in the beginning. This tells `apt` to use the package file that already is there in the directory where you execute the command.

Second, please check the exact filename. Maybe a newer version of the MySQL Workbench has been published since the tutorial was written, so the package isn't version 8.0.20 anymore.

Third, please check that you're executing `apt` from the directory where you've downloaded the package file to. Maybe you need to `cd` into your Downloads directory first, or something to that effect.

So, to summarize: First download the package file yourself, then go to the directory where the package file has been stored, then execute `apt install` with the filename the package file actually has.

Comment: what I did originally was according to what you said. I went to mysql's official website and downloaded the latest version, opened terminal, and typed cd Downloads, and typed the command in the question and got the error.

Comment: @hasanramp Did you check the second possible problem I mentioned? As of now, the MySQL workbench isn't at version 8.0.20, but at version 8.0.23. The filename has changed accordingly and is now `mysql-workbench-community_8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb`. Hand `apt` the exact name and position of the file you downloaded, even if the tutorial still refers to an older version.

Comment: As I said, I have downloaded the latest version i.e., mysql-workbench-community_8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb and i I typed the exact location of the file and it still shows the error 'Unsupported file ./Downloads/mysql-workbench-community_8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb given on commandline'.

Comment: what is the size of the downloaded file?